# Why the progress bar doesn't appear when click my button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I Make some calculation ,and this process takes time ,so i use  [RadProgressArea](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/progressarea/examples/customprogress/defaultcs.aspx)
.I want the progress bar to appear when i click the button which make the calculation , but the bar not appear at all !

```
 <telerik:RadProgressManager ID="Radprogressmanager1" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function onClientProgressBarUpdating(progressArea, args) {
            progressArea.updateVerticalProgressBar(args.get_progressBarElement(), args.get_progressValue());
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
```

---

```
<tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                &nbsp;
                <telerik:RadButton ID="btn_cal_real" runat="server" OnClick="btn_cal_real_Click"
                    Text="Calc">
                    <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbConfig" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4" />
                </telerik:RadButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <div class="qsf-demo-canvas">
        <telerik:RadProgressArea runat="server" ID="RadProgressArea1" OnClientProgressBarUpdating="onClientProgressBarUpdating">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="rpaInner">
                    <div class="rpaHeader">
                        <strong>Total Progress</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rpaBody">
                        <dl>
                            <dt class="rpaStatFirst">Total Progress Percent</dt>
                            <dd class="rpaStatFirst">
                                <span runat="server" id="PrimaryPercent"></span>%</dd>
                            <dt>Total Progress:</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <span runat="server" id="PrimaryValue"></span>
                            </dd>
                            <dt>Time Elapsed:</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <span runat="server" id="TimeElapsed"></span>
                            </dd>
                            <dt>Time Estimated:</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <span runat="server" id="TimeEstimated"></span>
                            </dd>
                            <dt>Transfer Speed:</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <span runat="server" id="Speed"></span>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </telerik:RadProgressArea>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to add more of your code to enable someone to determine the problem, e.g. what is the function `btn_cal_real_Click` doing?

Comment: @talegna :there's no code related to the `radprogressbar` ,just my calculation .

Comment: If you look at the Telerik demo you need to update the progress bar with your progress (see: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/progressarea/examples/customprogress/defaultcs.aspx#qsf-demo-source). If you think about it, how else is it to know how far through your calculation it is?

Comment: I want it with a button not with a `raduplouder`

Comment: The example linked to above is triggered by a button, I'm currently using it myself for displaying the progress of a complex save function so I can assure you the example will help.

Comment: @talegna : there 's no code in that example !!

Comment: Yes there is... press "View Source" at the top of the page, it's the same as on all the Telerik demo pages, it will show you the source only after you press that button it is hidden before that.